# Distribution of linear combination of Gaussian random variables

Tags: linear-algebra, probability, probability-distributions, random-variables, normal-distribution

Suppose that $x_1, x_2, \dots$ and $y_1, y_2, \dots$ are i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables. Define the following

$$z_n = \sum_{i=1}^n c_{ni} x_i + y_n$$

We know that $z_n$ is a zero-mean Gaussian random variable. For any $n\geq 1$, we can write

\begin{align}
z_{1:n} = \begin{bmatrix}
z_1\\
z_2\\
\vdots\\
z_n
\end{bmatrix} = \begin{bmatrix}
c_{11} & 0 & \dots & 0\\
c_{21} & c_{22} & \dots & 0\\
\vdots\\
c_{n1} & c_{n2} & \dots & c_{nn}
\end{bmatrix}\begin{bmatrix}
x_1\\
x_2\\
\vdots\\
x_n
\end{bmatrix}
+ I \begin{bmatrix}
y_1\\
y_2\\
\vdots\\
y_n
\end{bmatrix} = C_n x_{1:n} + I y_{1:n}
\end{align}

$z_{1:n}$ can be written as a linear combination of $n$ i.i.d. standard Gaussian random variables $v_1, \dots, v_n$

$$z_{1:n} = A_n v_{1:n},$$

where $A_nA^\intercal_n = C_nC^\intercal_n + I$. Intuitively, I expect $A_n$ to be lower triangular (similar to $C_n$) because of the causality in the problem. However, my simulations suggest that $A_n$ is not triangular. Could you please explain why my approach/intuition is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out that $A_n$ is not unique. In code, I used eigenvalue decomposition to compute $A_n$ and got a non-triangular matrix. To get a lower triangular matrix, use Cholesky decomposition.